# Angular download base64 file data

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

When I try to save on Angular a base64 file with this format :

```
// receivedFile.file = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR..."

var a = document.createElement('a');
const blob = new Blob([receivedFile.file], {type: receivedFile.infos.type});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = receivedFile.infos.name;
a.click();
```

This code give me a corrupted file, how can I do ?

Comment: What type do you use?

Comment: Its never the same. png/pdf/txt/jpg

Comment: Did you tried using file-saver-es package?

Comment: If your `receivedFile` is a string as the comment suggests - then what exactly do you think you are accessing with `receivedFile.infos.type` and `receivedFile.infos.name` here …?

Comment: Why create a new blob in the first place, if you already have a data URI? `a.href = receivedFile.file` should do the job already then, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular (and in general) I use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) :

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
const blob = new Blob([receivedFile], {type: receivedFile.infos.type});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, receivedFile.infos.name);
```

Also, try to remove the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part of the string :

```
receivedFile.file.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64," , "")
```

Comment: Still the same problem. Maybe the receivedFile format is wrong ?

Comment: Try removing `data:image/jpeg;base64,` from the beginning of the string

Comment: @Galileoomega maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code which converts base64 to downloadable file format in angular.

If for example your file type is csv, then below is the code snippet

```js
downloadFile(base64:any,fileName:any){
const src = `data:text/csv;base64,${base64}`;
const link = document.createElement("a")
link.href = src
link.download = fileName
link.click()

link.remove()
}

//calling above function with some sample base64 data
downloadFile("c21hbGxlcg==","demo.csv")
```

**Note**: The file type can be anything you can give based on the need(In **src** of above code snippet).Here I am considering the csv file as example.

So by calling this above function You can download the resultant file will be downloaded from browser.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem :

- Removed `data:image/jpeg;base64` from the receivedFile.file.
- Use the function `atob()`, `const byteCharacters = atob(receivedFile.file);`
- Then make the blob
  `const blob = new Blob([byteCharacters], {type: this.receivedFile.infos.type});`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
const fileName = 'sample.pdf';
downloadLink.href = linkSource;
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.click();
```